# /etc/resolv.conf is missing after installation of RHEL 8

Tags: resolv.conf, networkmanager, rhel8

I have installed RedHat Enterprise Linux 8.4 (minimal install) on my local server, and got some docker related issues.

Then I found that /etc/resolv.conf was missing.

After executing "systemctl reload NetworkManager", the file was made and docker worked.

I'm not sure why I have to reload NetworkManager to create resolv.conf and whether my network is working properly. Is there any common way to do this on RHEL8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, NetworkManager on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 8 dynamically updates the `/etc/resolv.conf` file with the DNS settings from active NetworkManager connection profiles.

If you don't want dynamic updates by NetworkManager set

```
[main]
dns=none
```

in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/90-dns-none.conf`

and reload the NetworkManager with

```
systemctl reload NetworkManager
```

The procedure is documented in more detail in the [RHEL 8 documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/manually-configuring-the-etc-resolv-conf-file_configuring-and-managing-networking)

Comment: run ```systemctl reload NetworkManager``` to fix the missing `/etc/resolv.conf`